# Linear equation $ax=b$ that holds for all $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the solution of the linear equation $$4x+k(2x-8)=16$$ is all numbers, find the value of $k$.

What I have tried:

\begin{align}
  4x+k(2x-8) &= 16 \\
  4x+2kx-8k &= 16 \\
  (4+2k)x &= 16+8k \\
  x &= \frac{16+8k}{4+2k} \\
  &= 4+4k
\end{align}

I am struggling please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "all numbers" do you mean integer? Also, your last step, the value of $x$ does not follow from the previous division.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve for $x$?   Try to solve for $k$.  That's the number you don't know.  You were told that $x$ can be anything.

Comment: If $4+2k$ does not equal $0$ you can divide both sides and you get that $x = 4$.  But if $4+2k = 0$ you can't divide both sides.  You get $0*x = 16+8x = 4(4+2k) = 4*0 =0$.  And $x$ can be anything.  You are told the answer is any number.  If $4+2k \ne 0$ you get that $x=4$ and $x$ can't be everything.  If $4+2k = 0$ you get that $x$ can be everything..... so what is $k$?

Answer (score 4):

You did well, but in your last step you made a mistake, because of awful notation.

You write $x=16+8k / 4+2k=4+4k$ what is not correct.

Also you meant $x=\frac{16+8k}{4+2k}$ note, that this only holds for $k\neq -2$ what you have to disclude, when dividing. That is important here.

With the correct result given above we can now write:

$x=\frac{8(2+k)}{2(2+k)}=4$

So $x=4$ but the equation has to hold for every $x$.

So let us check $k=-2$:

We get $4x-2(2x-8)=16\Leftrightarrow 4x-4x+16=16\Leftrightarrow 16=16$ and this is indeed correct for every $x$, because this equation does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you trying to solve for $k$?

Starting from

$$4x+k(2x-8)=16\tag{1}$$

you can first move $4x$ to the RHS

$$k(2x-8)=16-4x$$

and then provided that $x\neq 4$, you have

$$k = \frac{16-4x}{2x-8}=\frac{4(4-x)}{-2(4-x)}=-2$$

To check $x=4$, you can substitute $x=4$ into $(1)$ to form

$$16 + k(8-8)=16 \implies 16=16$$

So, $x=4$ works with every $k$.

Comment: The other method works also, but your is more coherent with the task. But you would have left to check the result $x=4$, since your calculation leaves that out, and we do not know if the equation holds for $k=-2$ and $x=4$, what it does.

Answer (score 1):

If $4+2k$ does not equal $0$ you can divide both sides and you get that $x = 4$.

But if $4+2k = 0$ you can't divide both sides.

You get $0*x = 16+8x = 4(4+2k) = 4*0 =0$.  And $x$ can be anything.

You are told the answer is any number.  If $4+2k \ne 0$ you get that $x=4$ and $x$ can't be everything.  If $4+2k = 0$ you get that $x$ can be everything.....

so what is $k$?

======

If the solution is all number then $x=4534856$ is a solution.

So $4\cdot 4534856 +k(2\cdot 4534856−8)=16$.

So what is $k$?

So $18139424 + 9069712k - 8k = 16$

$9069704 k = 16- 18139424= -18139408$

$k = \frac {-18139408}{9069704}=-2$.

If you don't like the number $4534856$ you can use $57493572574893257849326.87957893578493\cdot \sqrt{\pi}$.

Or as Laurie Anderson used to say:  Let $x = x$.

$4x+k(2x-8)=16$

$k(2x -8) = 16-4x$.

If $2x-8 \ne 0$ then we have

$k = \frac {16-4x}{2x- 8}= \frac {-4x+16}{2x -8} =-2$.

And If $2x - 8 =0$ then we have

$k(2x-8) = 16-4x = -4x+16 = -2(2x-8)$

$0*k = 0$

and we have no idea what $k$ is.... we have to use an $x$ where $2x-8\ne 0$ so  let $x = ..... $ anything that *isn't* $4$. and then $2x-8\ne 0$ and we can divide both sides by $2x-8$ and get $k=-2$

=======

Okay.... A more serious answer

you did

$(4 +2k) x = 16 + 8k$

And then you divided both sides by $4+2k$.

You can only divide by both sides by $4+2k$ if $4+2k \ne 0$.

If $4+2k \ne 0$ you get $x =\frac {16+8k}{4+2k} =4$.

And that is the one and only solution.  But you were told $x$ could be *any* number.

So you *know* you made a mistake.  The only mistake you could have made was dividing both sides by $4+2k$.  And the only way that that could be a mistake is if $4+2k = 0$.

So we *have* to have $4+2k = 0$ or else we wouldn't have made a mistake.

So $4+2k = 0$ and $k = -2$.

So we hae $(4+2k)x = 16+8k$

$0x = 16-16 = 0$.

So we have $0*x = 0$.  Well, that's true for all numbers!  Which is what we were told the answer was.